# Select plotting region levelplot

Tags: r

I have plotted a raster `x` using `levelplot`

```
levelplot(x, margin=FALSE ,xlab=list("",cex=1),ylab=list("",cex=1),col.regions=colorscale,                
          panel = function(x, y, ...) {
            panel.levelplot(x, y,  ...)
            mp <- map("world", plot = FALSE, fill=TRUE,interior = FALSE,bg="yellow")
            lpolygon(mp$x, mp$y, fill="black", col="black")},
          scales=list(x=x.scale, y=y.scale)
)
```

and this is what I get

[image]

What I want is to extend the plotting region to (-180,180) and (-90,90) so that the map is not cut. Can anyone help?

Comment: see `xlim` and `ylim` in `?levelplot`

Comment: We need to see `show(x)`

Answer (score 0):

`xlim` and `ylim` did the trick

```
levelplot(x, xlim=c(-180,180), ylim=c(-90,90),margin=FALSE ,xlab=list("",cex=1),ylab=list("",cex=1),col.regions=colorscale,                
          panel = function(x, y, ...) {
            panel.levelplot(x, y,  ...)
            mp <- map("world", plot = FALSE, fill=TRUE,interior = FALSE,bg="yellow")
            lpolygon(mp$x, mp$y, fill="black", col="black")},
          scales=list(x=x.scale, y=y.scale)
)
```